# Adding a specific-activity opening widget?

Tags: android, android-activity, widget

So I want to create a widget, more like a shortcut button though...which opens a specific activity screen of my app.

The full app with the menu and everything would be available/open-able by the normal android main menu...But the widget should just open a specific activity(Not the main activity)

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yes, there is. What did you try?

Comment: This will probably tell you everything you need to know about creating and controlling a widget.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

Inside `void onUpdate()` of your widget you should have something like

```
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.your_widget_layout);


    Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourActivityClass.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.your_widget_button, pendingIntent);
```

and in your application manifest you may want to have

```
    <activity
        android:excludeFromRecents="true" // if you do not want it to appear in recent applications list 
        android:name="com.example.yourapp.YourActivityClass"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_your_tittle" >
    </activity>
```